# AMC 8 Practice Questions

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> We know from the triangle inequality that the last side, $s$, fulfills $s<5+19=24$. Adding $5+19$ to both sides of the inequality, we get $s+5+19<48$, and because $s+5+19$ is the perimeter of our triangle, $48$ is our answer.

This is what is stated in the AMC 8 practice problem. I understand every part of this answer except for the last part.

The choices for this problem are

> a) $24$
>   b) $29$
>   c) $43$
>   d) $48$
>   e) $57$

I know that the answer has to be greater than $24$, yet has to be the smallest number that is, from what I understand, smaller than $48$. Why would $48$ be the answer, and not $29$?

================================================================

> On her first day of work, Janabel sold one widget. On day two, she sold three widgets. On day three, she sold five widgets, and on each succeeding day, she sold two more widgets than she had sold on the previous day. How many widgets in total had Janabel sold after working $20$ days?

This is the prompt for an AMC 8 practice problem. If I'm not mistaken, this is an example of a quadratic relationship. I know that the quadratic formula is $Ax^2+Bx+C=0$. If this is in fact a quadratic relationship, how exactly would I plug the values in?

However, one solution states:

> The sum of $1,3,5, ........ 39$ is $\frac{(1+39)(20)}{2}=400$.

I am confused on why you would add all the numbers up. And why add $1$, then multiply by $20$, then divide by $2$? Could someone explain why you would do that?

Here's what the second solution states:

> The sum is just the sum of the first $20$ odd integers, which is $20^2=400$.

Again, could someone reword this to make more sense? And why would this work? (possibly include a visual of some sort)

And why couldn't I use a quadratic formula to solve this problem, if this is in fact a quadratic relationship? Is this another type of relationship?

Also, it would be a huge help if you could help me out on all of my AMC 8 questions on my profile. I am taking the AMC 8 test tomorrow, and I am not the brightest student. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you have multiple questions that are not closely related, you should ask them in separate posts.

Comment: @EricWofsey I am truly sorry about that; it's just that I can only post every 20 minutes, and I need by questions answered as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking it today too!

For the second problem

{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39}

Janabel has sold this amount of widgets in each of those days.

Notice that by adding 1 and 39, you get a sum of 40.
Adding 3 and 37, you also get 40.
5 and 35? Still 40.

So what the solution has essentially done is group the numbers in that list so they're a bit easier to add.

{1,39,3,37,5,35,7,33,9,31,11,29,13,27,15,25,17,23,19,21}

Each of these pairs adds up to 40, and there are 10 pairs (20/2 because there are 20 numbers, and 2 form a pair).

Hence (39 + 1) * 20 / 2.

I hope you understand now, good luck on the test!

Comment: thank you, and sorry for the lateness. This makes a lot more sense now! I'm pretty sure I failed the test, but there's always next year!

Comment: Hey no problem, I got stuck on some of them too! If you have any other questions, feel free to ask the community, and we'll try to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

For the triangle, the question asked for the smallest integer larger than the perimeter of any possible triangle with two sides of 5 and 19.  The remaining side must be at least 19-5 and no more than 19+5.  The minimum doesn't matter, only the maximum.

As for the other, the sum of an arithmetic series is $S_n = {n (a_1 + a_n) \over 2}$

Comment: oh okay, that makes a little more sense. I understand why the remaining side must be greater than 14, but why exactly does the remaining side have to be smaller than 24? And even when I plug the numbers back into the inequality, it doesn't quite make sense. s+5+19<48. s+24<48. None of the answers would work, because even 24+24 is not less than 48.

Comment: s has to be less than 24 in order to not be too long for the other two sides to reach its end-points.  The maximum reach of of a side of 5 and a side of 19 is 24.  So s < 24.and so the maximum perimeter for the triangle is less than 24 + 5 + 19; in other words, the maximum perimeter is less than 48.  So, 48 is the smallest integer larger than the maximum possible perimeter.

Comment: ah, I got it now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For the second problem 
Another way to solve the problem
Since this is problem #9 in AMC 8, this should be relatively easy to solve and you should be able to solve it in under a minute. But a quick look will tell you that the arithmetic might take quite a bit of time. So what do we do?
Let's try listing it out
[Click here to see the pattern](https://www.vsonlinemathtutoring.com/blog/math-competition-problems-problem-of-the-week-2). (It won't let me format my text).
Now that we have listed it out we can see a pattern. 
The no. of widgets she sold on Day 1 is 1^2 
The total no. of widgets she sold till Day 2 is 2^2
The total no. of widgets she sold till Day 3 is 3^2
The total no. of widgets she sold till Day 4 is 4^2
So the number of widgets she sold till Day n can be summed up by the expression n^2
So the total no. of widgets Janabel sold after working 20 days is 20^2 = 400.

This type of problem-solving technique is called finding a pattern. I hope this clears it up.
For more of these kinds of problems visit https://www.vsonlinemathtutoring.com/problem-of-the-week